# Support for const_string in std::ostream operator <<

Tags: c++, templates, string, boost, ostream

I'm currently using the very clever package [`boost::const_string`](http://conststring.sourceforge.net/) until http://libcxx.llvm.org/ is available pre-packaged on Ubuntu or GCC make its `__versa_string` (in header `ext/vstring.h`) its default string implementation. libcxx's `std::string` aswell as `__versa_string` uses _small-string optimization (SSO) by default. Default support for outputting to an `std::ostream` is lacking however. The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/const_string.hpp>

const_string<char> x;
std::cout << x << endl;
```

does not work unless we force `x` into a c-string via `c_str()` which becomes

```
std::cout << x.c_str() << endl;
```

which compiles and works as expected. I added the following line to `const_string.hpp`

```
template <typename T>
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const boost::const_string<T> & a)
{
    return os.write(a.data(), a.size());
}
```

This should improve performance over `x.c_str()` because `size()` is already known and does not need to be calculated by searching for `NULL` as in `c_str()`. I works for me but I am uncertain whether it works all cases. Have I missed something?

Comment: That depends on which behaviour you want for non-printable characters (especially `\0`), I guess. I think (!) the default behaviour for normal strings is to truncate after null chars. Your implementation probably won’t do that. By the way, +1 for making me aware of `boost::const_string`.

Comment: I think this is a kind of trade-off.
As far as I see, your code doesn't reflect manipulator settings like
`std::setw`.
If you don't use those manipulators for `const_string`,
I think your code has its own use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Have I missed something?

Yes, just include `const_string/io.hpp`. All it does however is:

```
return o << std::basic_string<char_type, traits_type>(s.data(), s.size());
```

Comment: Is that as fast as my alternative?

Comment: @Nordlöw: Quite likely, e.g. it construct a temporary `basic_string` - but then again you don't have to deal with locales et al. Anyway, i'd measure it if it really matters in your application.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this could have implications based on the locale and/or facets applied to the stream for strings vs just writing the straight data as you're doing.

It would be less performant, but what about creating a std::string from the const_string and using `<<` to insert that into the stream?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How do I support locale settings then?

Answer (score 1):

No (you have not missed anything, afaik). If your aim is not to copy over content, str.data() is the way to go.